# Koshuke Github api 403 forbidden after certain time

Tags: java, spring, github-api

I have around 20 githubs that I update some information for with the koshuke GitHub API:

```
try {
    settings = settingsRepository.findById(1).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("No settings found"));
    GitHub gitHub = GitHub.connect(settings.getUsername(), settings.getToken());

    GHRepository repo;
    try {
        repo = gitHub.getRepository(gitHubModel.getUser() + "/" + gitHubModel.getRepo());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new GitHubRepositoryException("Couldn't connect to " + gitHubModel.getLink() + ". Check URL.");
}
```

There is event that loops around them on every 2-3 seconds, takes one of the githubs, updates it and after 2-3 seconds continues to the next one. After certain amount of updates the code stops at:

```
repo = gitHub.getRepository(gitHubModel.getUser() + "/" + gitHubModel.getRepo());.
```

I tried debugging and found out that it stops at certain point and it throws 403 Forbidden:

```
private <T> T parse(Class<T> type, T instance, int timeouts) throws IOException {
    InputStreamReader r = null;
    int responseCode = -1;
    String responseMessage = null;
    try {
        responseCode = uc.getResponseCode();
        responseMessage = uc.getResponseMessage();
        if (responseCode == 304) {
            return null;    // special case handling for 304 unmodified, as the content will be ""
        }
        if (responseCode == 204 && type!=null && type.isArray()) {
            // no content
            return type.cast(Array.newInstance(type.getComponentType(),0));
        }

        r = new InputStreamReader(wrapStream(uc.getInputStream()), "UTF-8");
        String data = IOUtils.toString(r);
        if (type!=null)
            try {
                return setResponseHeaders(MAPPER.readValue(data, type));
            } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                throw (IOException)new IOException("Failed to deserialize " +data).initCause(e);
            }
        if (instance!=null) {
            return setResponseHeaders(MAPPER.readerForUpdating(instance).<T>readValue(data));
        }
        return null;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // java.net.URLConnection handles 404 exception has FileNotFoundException, don't wrap exception in HttpException
        // to preserve backward compatibility
        throw e;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (e instanceof SocketTimeoutException && timeouts > 0) {
            LOGGER.log(INFO, "timed out accessing " + uc.getURL() + "; will try " + timeouts + " more time(s)", e);
            return parse(type, instance, timeouts - 1);
        }
        throw new HttpException(responseCode, responseMessage, uc.getURL(), e);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(r);
    }
}
```

Then the exception is consumed and it comes to a point where it calls Thread.sleep and stops there.
Is this because I have exceeded the limit of requests? Somewhere I have read that it is 5000 request a minute and I am not doing that many. Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: According to https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting the rate limit is 5,000 requests per _hour_, not minute. And according to https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#rate-limit the rate limit is different for searches: 30 requests per _minute_. Both rates are for authenticated users.

Comment: @Slaw I increased the rate and instead of updating only once I looped 30 times every github. For several minutes now it should have made around 600 request, so it doesn't stop at 30 per minute. Also without the 30 loop I am pretty sure it doesn't make 5000 request per hour. I will create a count and check it.

Comment: I just saw you mention you read the rate limit was 5K per minute and I decided to look into that (since that seemed high) and report back my findings. Unfortunately, if that doesn't help solve the problem I won't be much help.